# jqgrid how to refresh the page, using python-django

Tags: jqgrid, refresh

all,

For jqgrid refresh, I will not say it reload, as after add/edit, the data is inserted/updated in mysql database, I need a page refresh to get the data from database and then display in the grid. I tried a lot solutions about

```
$("#submit").click(){}
```

and

```
jQuery.("#list").trigger('reloadGrid')
```

But all do not work. May I Know how can I refresh the page after hit the "submit" button in jqGrid form? From the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942111/django-python-jqgrid-form-editing-error-status-forbidden-error-code-403), you can see the setting for my grid. Thanks very much

Solution: Solved my problem in the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551933/i-need-jqgrid-to-refresh-the-entire-page-not-just-the-grid/26553697#comment50414837_26553697). Hope it can help others. Thanks

Comment: have you tried the events? http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

Comment: @Paulo, thanks for your reply. I tried event afterComplete mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297940/jqgrid-reload-other-grids-after-edit , but this seems also related to 'relaodGrid', so it dose not work. I did not find an event to refresh the whole page.